# Adding Multiplicative Identity to make an Algebra Unital

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Consider the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}^{\omega\times\omega}$ consisting of all maps $\mathbf{A}:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbf{A}(n,m)\neq 0$ for only finitely-many pairs $(n,m)$, with the obvious addition and scalar multiplication rules.

Now suppose I have a binary operation $\ast$ on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega\times\omega}$ which makes it into a commutative associative algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. We may assume that $\ast$ acts extremely well locally, i.e.: every finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega\times\omega}$ is contained in a finitely-generated subspace which is closed under $\ast$ and in which $\ast$ has a multiplicative identity (for that subspace).

For example, $\ast$ could be either Hadamard multiplication (coordinate-wise multiplication) or matrix multiplication.

Is it possible to show that it isn't possible to add a single element $\mathbb{I}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{\omega\times \omega}$ and expand the definitions of $\ast,+,\cdot$ so that $\mathbb{I}$ acts as a multiplicative identity for $\ast$, retaining all the original properties of the operations (associativity, commutativity, distributivity, etc)?

(It's alright if this can only be shown for the two example operations above, but it'd be nice if there were a general method for showing that such identities cannot be added.

Also, the choice of $\mathbb{R}$ was arbitrary; in truth I'm actually considering arbitrary commutative semirings, giving rise to semialgebras instead.)

Comment: Why do you suspect that it *isn't* possible?  In the matrix setting, I don't see why we couldn't add in the infinite identity matrix.  At least, I don't see any issues unless you were to bring in some sort of topological structure.

Comment: The issue is that I only want to add a single element. If I add in the infinite identity matrix with the usual definitions of addition, then I'm going to get a whole lot of other matrices that weren't in there to start with.